# CSS class isn't running when I add it in JS fike

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am still very new to CSS and JS but I've looked this over several times, checked w2schools, and searched for similar questions, and I still don't know where I am going wrong.

```
     <! DOC TYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<h1> fruit dodge</h1>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="FDCSS.css">
</head>
<body onkeypress="jump()">
<div id="game">
    
    <div id="player"></div>
```

I moved the event to the body hoping it would fix the problem but it was originally on the html tag and it still was not working.

```
CSS:
.animate
{
    animation: jump 500ms;
}
keyframes jump
{
    0%{top: 400px;}
    30%{top: 350px;}
    70%{top: 350px;}
    100%{top: 400px;}
}
```

I know the animation itself works because I tested it prior to trying to add it to a class.

```
var player = getElementById("player");
var fruit = getElementById("fruit");

    function jump()
    {
        player.classList.add("animate");
        setTimeout(function()
        {
            player.classList.remove("animate");
        },500);
    }
```

the jump function is supposed to add the animate class to the player character and then remove it and wait the duration of the animation(500ms).

Comment: It should be `@keyframes` See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes

Comment: It's `document.getElementById`, not just `getElementById`.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of errors in your code. In the CSS part, you need to add an `@` symbol in front of [keyframes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes).

Also, you shouldn't animate the `top` value and should prefer hardware accelerated properties like `transform`. (see the example below)

```
.animate {
  animation: jump 500ms;
}

@keyframes jump {
  from {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateY(-40px);
  }
}
```

In the JS part, there is no global `getElementById()`, you need to use [`document.getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) to select your elements.

```
var player = document.getElementById("player");
var fruit = document.getElementById("fruit");

function jump() {
  player.classList.add("animate");

  setTimeout(function () {
    player.classList.remove("animate");
  }, 500);
}
```

```js
var player = document.getElementById("player");
var btn = document.getElementById("btn");

function jump() {
  player.classList.add("animate");

  setTimeout(function() {
    player.classList.remove("animate");
  }, 500);
}

btn.addEventListener("click", jump);
```

```css
.player {
  background-color: #a1887f;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 3rem;
  margin: 4rem auto 1rem;
  width: 3rem;
}

button {
  background-color: #c5e1a5;
  border: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
}

.animate {
  animation: jump 500ms;
}

@keyframes jump {
  from {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateY(-40px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="player" id="player"></div>
<button id="btn">Jump</button>
```